# How to configure PMD rulesets for different configurations in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, pmd

I'm able to configure the PMD plugin for Gradle and do root level configuration.
I'm able to configure those settings for a particular sourceSet(s).

What I'm trying to figure out is how to configure certain PMD rulesets for one sourceSet (main) and different PMD rulesets for another (test).

For example:

- Apply java-basic and java-braces for main (pmdMain Gradle task)
- Apply java-junit for test (pmdTest Gradle task)

What does the build.gradle file need to look like to accomplish this?  Is this even possible with the PMD plugin in Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a plugin such as [this one](https://github.com/monits/static-code-analysis-plugin), or do it manually:

```
apply plugin: 'pmd'

project.tasks['pmdMain'] {
  ruleSets = ['java-basic', 'java-braces']
}

project.tasks['pmdTest'] {
  ruleSets = ['java-junit']
}
```